# Using the genres filter on Soundcloud's Ruby API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, soundcloud

I'm using the [soundcloud gem](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby) and it's not quite working as expected.

`client.get('/me/tracks')` returns all my tracks, like I'd expect.

`client.get('me/tracks', :genres => "Jazz")` returns 50 jazz tracks from various users.

Obviously my goal is to get all of my tracks in the Jazz genre. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The API has limit of 50 tracks per request. You can use `offset` parameter to get the next set of tracks. Look here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#pagination

Comment: I'm trying to limit the tracks to those that I own. It's returning me 50 tracks from *various* users despite the fact that the path is 'me/tracks'